# Changing degrees to meters

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude, heat-map

[image]I'm using QGIS 3.4.9. When I try to create a heatmap the only radius option is degrees. Can you tell me how to change this to meters?

Comment: This is because your layer is in a projection that has degrees as units (4326). You need first to reproject your layer to a projection that has meters as units (like 3857) and then you'll be able to use meters as units in the radius of the heatmap.

Comment: What @LéoM said, I would just add that you should try to find a coordinate reference system specifically for the region you are working in, going by the coordinates in your screenshot you should look for the best fitting coordinate reference system for South Africa.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees...

Answer (score 1):

Most plugins use the Reference System of the project.
To determine the choice of units to use, the Heatmap Plugin you use looks at the Reference System of your project. In your case it finds out it is EPSG:4326 (as you can see in the lower bottom of your QGIS window), which is WGS84.
Since the WGS84 Reference System is not projected, it uses geographical coordinates (lat and long) which are expressed in degrees.
Hence the `degree` unit you are proposed.

To change Reference System of your project, click on the `EPSG:4326` label on the bottom right of the QGIS window, and select a projected system.
Then try your Heatmap plugin again.

[image]